# Not getting full list of favorited tracks by me via SoundCloud api (even with the use of offset)

Tags: api, list, soundcloud, offset, favorites

I am trying to load the full list of favorited tracks by me in a list object using the SoundCloud api. I am using the offset parameter to load all favorited tracks 50 at a time. Unfortunately, it stops at 8000 favorites while my list contains over 20000 likes.
Why is it not returning all favorited tracks?
It does not matter if I use the "me" (by using a token) or the "user" method (by using my user id).

Any idea how to overcome this?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

Pagination section of the SoundCloud API documentation (http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide) states this:

> The maximum value is 200 for `limit` and 8000 for `offset`.

That probably explains the behavior you are seeing. I am not sure how to get around it though.